# How to find an ether account I sent to from CoinBase

Tags: transactions, coinbase

I had some Ethereum. I originally bought at Coinbase, but after hearing talk about keeping a separate wallet for your digital currency I transferred them to another place.

That was a year ago. I wrote my receive address down, but I switched computers and don't remember where my Ethereum account is.

I have a record of the send from Coinbase, but I don't remember where I sent my ETH.

Can anyone please provide some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Coinbase sends you an email whenever you send out ETH. The email contains the receiver address. It looks like the following one:

> You just sent 0.5 ETH to 0x2900000000000000
>
> Congratulations! You have successfully sent 0.5 ETH (worth xxx USD) to 0x2900000000000000 using Coinbase. To facilitate this transaction, you paid 0.00042 ETH (worth xxx USD) in network fees.

From the email you can determine what is the recipient address. In this case, the example is `0x2900000000000000`

However, this is as far as you can go. You can't determine what was the wallet or where you hosted it from the address.

Having the address, you may try to search your computer for something that references it. But if you don't find anything, and more importantly if you don't find the private key (or a backup), then there is no chance to recover the amount.

Comment: Thank you very much Simone ... Your answer was complete and very helpful.
Continued blessings to you, my friend!